# How to check if a parameter contains two substrings using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a line in my test that currently looks like:

```
Mockito.verify(mockMyObject).myMethod(Mockito.contains("apple"));
```

I would like to modify it to check if the parameter contains both `"apple"` and `"banana"`.  How would I go about this?

Comment: Check this article [Argument matching with Mockito](http://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/argument-matching-with-mockito) for working example.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just use `Mockito.matches(String)`, for example:

```
Mockito.verify(mockMyObject).
  myMethod(
    Mockito.matches("(.*apple.*banana.*)|(.*banana.*apple.*)"
  )
);
```

Answer (score 26):

Since Java 8 and Mockito 2.1.0, it is possible to use Streams as follows:

```
Mockito.verify(mockMyObject).myMethod(
    Mockito.argThat(s -> s.contains("apple") && s.contains("banana"))
);
```

thus improving readability

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like a useful and more up-to-date answer. I asked this question 9 years ago, and so it might be worth mentioning the versions of Java (e.g. Java 8 streams) and/or Mockito (the docs mention this interface changed in 2.1.0: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.24.5/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#argThat-org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher- ).

Comment: Since Java 9 it could be written even shorter: `Mockito.argThat(s -> List.of("apple", "banana").contains(s))`.

Answer (score 15):

I think the easiest solution is to call the verify() multiple times:

```
verify(emailService).sendHtmlMail(anyString(), eq(REPORT_TITLE), contains("Client response31"));
verify(emailService).sendHtmlMail(anyString(), eq(REPORT_TITLE), contains("Client response40"));
verify(emailService, never()).sendHtmlMail(anyString(), anyString(), contains("Client response30"));
```

Comment: I do not agree with your answer because it could be different method calls and you could not know it for sure. FYI I did not vote your answer down.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this is not relevant anymore but I found another way to do it, following Torsten answer and this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17403934/6031679). In my case I used Hamcrest [Matchers](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html)

```
Mockito.verify(mockMyObject).myMethod(
   Mockito.argThat(Matchers.allOf(
      Matchers.containsString("apple"),
      Matchers.containsString("banana"))));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Mockito's `AdditionalMatchers`:

```
Mockito.verify(mockMyObject).myMethod(
AdditionalMatchers.and(Mockito.contains("apple"), Mockito.contains("banana")));
```

More info https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html#and(T,T)