# Want a JUnitMatchers AssertThat to test string contains 3 or more sub strings (currently using assertThat ... both ... and ....)

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

```
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.both;
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.containsString;
```

Now I check it contains foo and bar as below ...

```
        Assert.assertThat(text,
            both(containsString("foo")).
            and(containsString("bar")));
```

What is cleanest way to test that it contains 3 or more strings e.g. 'foo', 'bar' and 'baz' ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [AllOf](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#allOf%28org.hamcrest.Matcher...%29)

```
 Assert.assertThat(test, CoreMatchers.allOf(
      containsString("foo"),
      containsString("bar"),
      containsString("bar2"),
      containsString("ba3")));
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know a elegant way in pure JUnit but you could take a look at [Fixtures for Easy Software Testing](http://fest.easytesting.org/)

I'm using it for quite some time and it makes like so much easier.

```
assertThat(text).contains("foo").contains("bar");
```

Comment: +1 FEST/[AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/). You could use `assertThat(text).contains("foo", "bar", "baz");` - it's even more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a static method that provides some syntactic sugar for this:

```java
public static org.hamcrest.Matcher<String> containsAll(String... substrings) {
    List<Matcher<? super String>> matchers =
            Arrays.stream(substrings)
                    .map(s -> CoreMatchers.containsStringIgnoringCase(s))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return CoreMatchers.allOf(matchers);
}
```

Usage:

```java
assertThat(someValue, containsAll("foo", "bar"));
```